# The actual age of each yuga

Tags: bhagavata-purana, yuga

Puranas extensively mention the length of a mahayuga or a chaturyuga to be of 12000 divine years or 4,320,000 human years. This period is divided in 4:3:2:1 in 4 subsequent Yugas.
But Yukteshwar Giri, in his book the holy science, addressed these numbers as inflated figures due to lack of understanding among seers around 2900 years ago. This resulted in introduction of this extra "divya varsh" concept( a multiplication of actual figure with 360) . He explained that, in reality, each mahayuga cycle is divided in ascending and decending period of 12000 human years each. We are currently living in 322nd year of Dwapara which started in 1700 AD.
Which of the 2 explanations is more authentic : The one which is discussed in puranas or the one put forward by Yukteshwar Giri in his book ?

Comment: Puranas. It ranks higher in Sabda Pramana than Yukteshwar Giri

Comment: YDS actually I am aware of Vishnu Purana's description. Yukteshwar addressed these inflations in puranas as nothing but mistakes in translation that began some 2900 years ago.

Comment: That contradicts so many things. For example at the end (and quite a bit before) of Kali Yuga Rakshasas are on Earth. They are kind of hard to miss.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I will recommend you to read [this](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.281640/page/n199/mode/1up)

Secondly , Both theories are wrong . I will explain why.

**Proof 1**

[Ramayana ayodhya kanda sarga 71 verse 1-2](https://archive.org/details/wg966/page/n429/mode/2up?view=theater)(english translation of one part of verse)

> crossed the west flowing sutlej river

So when bharat was returning back to ayodhya , he encountered sutlej river which was flowing in west . Now in present day sutlej flows in west direction too. [2017 research paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01643-9) says-

> Analysis shows that the Ghaggar–Hakra palaeochannel is a former course of the Himalayan Sutlej River that formed and occupied an incised valley from **at least ~23 ka** .Initial abandonment of this incised valley by the Sutlej River commenced **after ~15 ka**, with complete avulsion to its present course shortly after **~8 ka**.

**ka means 1 thousand years ago** . So basically sutlej river started changing its course from 13000 BC and and by 5000BC it was flowing in west direction.Below picture shows that sutlej flowed in south direction from 21000BC(23 ka) till 13000BC(15 ka) .[image: sutlej course]

**Proof 2**

[Ramayana sundara kanda sarga 4 verse 26-28](http://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/sundara/sarga4/sundara_4_frame.htm)

> The great Hanuma entered secretly Ravana's inner city which was equal to paradise, rendered noisy by neighing of horses and tinkling of ornaments, by chariots, vehicles and aerial-cars and decorated by auspicious elephants and horses and **great elephants with four tusks** and by birds and animals in heat. It had beautiful entrances and was protected by thousands of rakshasas with great strength.

So Hanuman saw 4 tusked elephant called as Gomphothere.[This](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Radiocarbon-dating-for-archaeological-paleontological-sites-with-gomphothere-remains_tbl1_233663623) paper shows the table in which bones of gomphothere have been carbon dated and roughly they date from 17000BC-7000BC . (All dates are in Bp means before present) So its clear ramayana happened somewhere between 13000-7000BC .But this date doesn't match with puranas nor with Yukteshwar 's theory.

Comment: Bro this direction of sutlej river angle is applied by Nilesh Oak as well to lock ramayanas age to be 13k BC but the reality is rivers keep on changing their directions because of various reasons .This phenomenon of a river changing its coarse is rare but still it happens. Read about the Damodar river in bihar which keeps changing its path every now and then.